# Showing $x^{p^e}-a$ is irreducible in imperfect field of characteristic p

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$, and $f(x)=x^{p^e}-a$, where $a \in F-F^p$.  I wish to show $f(x)$ is irreducible.

I know $x^{p^e}=a$ has no solutions in $F$.  Thus, $f(x)$ cannot have linear factors.  Also, $f'(x)=0$, so $f$ is inseparable.  I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: This should be in numerous abstract algebra books. I am pretty sure it is in Jacobson's Basic Algebra I or II. If you really can't find it, see Lemma 2.1 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf.